# Отсутствие класса OpenFileDialog в библиотеке Microsoft.Win32

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в решении два проекта. В главном проекте я могу обратиться к классу следующим образом:`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`.
А в другом не могу, видимо не хватает какой-то ссылки.
Вот скрин ссылок, во втором проекте:

---

[image: Ссылки]

Comment: Вы знаете где лежит этот класс? Я не вижу у вас ссылки на `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс который вы хотите использовать в вашем проекте, находится в библиотеке `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Добавьте ссылку на данную библиотеку.

Подробнее на [Microdost.Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.5).

Answer (score 2):

добавьте `System.Windows.Forms`

`System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();`

Comment: WPF исключает использование System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Да ладно? С момента выхода WPF можно было использовать смешанные решения даже на одном контроле. Другой вопрос - насколько это реально надо? Но это уже другой вопрос, иногда надо.